# How to get post category name

Tags: json, angularjs, wordpress

How I get post category name using AngularJS with WP-JSON in Wordpress

`{{post.title}}` working
`{{post.content}}` working
`{{post.terms.category.name}}` not working
or
`{{post.category.name}}` not working

Thanks

Comment: Maybe post post object structure?

Comment: nothing is clear from your description ,no angular code provided and no json provided .How someone can answer your question untill they wont understant ur problem

Comment: here is my json code "terms":{"category":[{"ID":36,"name":"Blog","slug":"blog","description":"","taxonomy":"category","parent":null,"count":9,"link":"http:\/\/scottbolinger.com\/category\/blog\/","meta":{"links":{"collection":"test"}}}]}}

Comment: post this in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `{{post.terms.category.name}}` you are coming close. However `{{post.terms.category}}` contains an array. You will have to loop through these values.

To test you can use the first item in line: `{{post.terms.category[0].name}}` should work for your example.

Comment: great its working. but I have multiple categories in one post, how I can render all? thanks

Comment: That depends on how you set-up your controller and/or view logic. I guess [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) in your view is a good starting point.